# Why the clock under Windows 7 shows a quick tick for every 6 slow ticks?

Tags: windows, timer

If you watch windows' clock under windows 7 carefully, you will find there is quick tick for every 6 slow tick(with the same length).

I googled, find an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2008/05/27/why-the-clock-under-windows-2k-xp-2k3-show-four-quick-seconds-and-one-slow-second.aspx?Redirected=true) that tells `windows 2K/XP/2K3` set the clock by:

```
SetTimer (hWnd, TimerID, OPEN_TLEN, 0L);
```

and it gives that explain:

> OPEN_TLEN is the length of the timer, it is a constant. So when we
>   look at clock.h, you will get the number, which is 450. What does this
>   450 mean? This means, every 450ms the timer will be triggered, it will
>   detect time changes and redraw the clock.

then he mentioned my problem:

> BTW – the clock application under Vista/2K8 is completely rewritten,
>   so you may not have that problem. But if you watch it for a minute,
>   you will still notice a quite “quick” second. :)

If what he said is true, there is no doubt with the unusual behavior of the clock, but my question is:

Why the developer of windows choose that weird `450ms`? If it's `500ms`, every tick will show with same length.

And in windows 7, they rewrote the clock and don't fix the problem at all, I think, there must be some reason, the developer have to choose that weird redrawing time.

So I want to know, what is the mysterious reason?

Comment: No, 500 would not have helped. Timers don't fire on time. They fire when the application empties the queue. They are not accurate. They won't fire early but they can fire late.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to know the answer.

Comment: The [Nyquist Shannon sampling theorom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) applies here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clock will register a timer for **1s** and simply move the "seconds" hand every time the timer handler is triggered.

> Depending upon the dynamic system load, the tick-ing movement of the "seconds" hand will be a few milliseconds delayed at every iteration.

Once in a while (not sure how often, but seems like a minute at most), the clock app will check the actual system time to sync the timer (and hence the movement of the "seconds" hand). At this moment, it will catch-up with the actual time and all the delay accumulated over the past few iterations will be corrected. **This is observed as a quick tick of the "seconds" hand of the clock.**

---

#### Why is this done?

The clock app is NOT guaranteed to be accurate to the millisecond. As checking the system time once every second is expensive it is avoided with the above re-design. However, to compensate for "drift" of the time shown on the clock-app (w.r.t. the actual system time) the app **does** check the system-time once in a while; ergo the "fast" tick.

Comment: Is there any reference?

Comment: This is a common design-pattern when designing clocks. Currently, i do NOT have any authoritative document for the Windows clock. The behaviour observed **IS** the conclusion/reference.